# Who is Mathias Tumm and why is he rewarding me?

Tags: the-witcher-2

In Act I, a man named Mathias Tumm appears in the yard in front of Bernard Loredo's residence, next to the stall containing armor and weapons racks, and a large chest.  I believe he first appears after:

> Geralt kills the Kayran.

[image]

He acts as if Geralt has done a service for him, but I do not remember such.  [He gives you, at least, a recipe for Red Haze.](http://www.gog.com/en/forum/the_witcher_2/q_who_is_mathias_tumm)  I have confirmed this.

Why does he do this?  Does Geralt meet him at any point earlier in the story?

Comment: Hmm, would make the most sense if he was in the first game but I can't find any references. Maybe he's in the books.

Comment: You sure he's not rewarding you for killing the Kayran?

Comment: While it's possible, as the timing fits, I don't remember him having anything to do with the Kayran dialogues and the way he says "You found me?" suggests to me that he must have had previous direct contact with Geralt and that it likely had to do with something outside of Flotsam.  (Also thank you for editing in my pic when I didn't have rep for it.)

Answer (score 2):

Is he a villager you rescued from guards in the prologue perhaps?  I had a similar encounter with a woman in flotsam.

Comment: That's an interesting hypothesis, and one I find reasonable.  Let's see if someone can confirm it.

Comment: While I can't personally rule this answer out since I've not replayed the prologue, this gamer feels fairly strongly that it's not the case:  [http://www.gog.com/en/forum/the_witcher_2/q_who_is_mathias_tumm/post9](http://www.gog.com/en/forum/the_witcher_2/q_who_is_mathias_tumm/post9)

Comment: I just redid the prologue.  While you don't see the names of any of the saved villagers, none of them share the same model so my hunch was probably wrong.

Answer (score 2):

He resembles Raymond Tassel, the merchant at Loredo's who tells you to get the Iron Frame for the Kayran trap. I wonder if they're supposed to be the same person. Has anyone had the Mathias Tumm encounter before meeting Raymond Tassel during the Indecent Proposal quest?

After retrieving the frame from behind Loredo's residence, Geralt's last words to Raymond are "I still need a few things, but you helped me a lot." to which he replies, "You'll find me at the market. Best of luck witcher." I don't recall seeing him anywhere after that, but I ran into Mathias the next time I went to Loredo's.

Comment: Interesting thought.  So you are thinking the NPC's name was accidentally changed between phases of the quest?  It's possible although it's weird that he'd reward Geralt when he was actually helping Geralt.  Was that the object we get from behind Laredo's residence?

Comment: Well, Raymond Tassel wanted the Kayran dead, so Geralt clearly helped with that. And I wouldn't put a name switch out of the question -- the game guide, and indeed several places in-game, referr to the "Beehive" bomb, which was renamed the "Grapeshot" bomb in the final version.